# I want to add new option to table row on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I want to add a new option to the table cell on hover in ReactJS:

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here what I have done so far:

[image]

I don't know how to hover on it and change the table cell of material UI and add that remove option to it.

Here is my ReactJS:

```
                                <TableRow key={row.name}>
                                    <TableCell style={{ verticalAlign: 'middle', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end' }} align="left">
                                        <SupervisedUserCircleRoundedIcon style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} />
                                        {row.importedGroups}
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="left">{row.importedAs}</TableCell>
                                    {/* <TableCell align="left">
                                        <Select
                                            value={selected}
                                            onChange={handleChange}
                                            name="select_importas"
                                            style={{ minWidth: 120, font: 'normal normal 600 16px/22px Open Sans' }}
                                            displayEmpty
                                        >
                                            <MenuItem value="">Normal Group</MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem value="super_Group">Super Group</MenuItem>
                                        </Select>
                                    </TableCell> */}
                                </TableRow>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.MuiTableCell-root {
    border-bottom: none !important;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I just want to change the color of Table cell color on hover and add a visible option of `Remove` to it as shown in the screenshot above in material UI.

Answer (score 0):

Your code that you shared not clear to understand your question hovewer you can do `display: none` for the component&icon that you do not want to show without hover then when there is hover you can do `display: block` in your css

Comment: The screenshot which I have shared shows Remove button on hover. But when we take the mouse pointer off from it the remove option becomes invisible. How to do it??

Comment: You can do it with my answer easily just display: none when there is no hover and display: block on hover. That's it :)